# How can I customize a kendo scheduler popup window

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm wondering if there is a way to customize the window that pops up when you click on the kendo scheduler. I would like to remove the "all day event" checkbox.

Comment: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-editable.template

Answer (score 9):

Also consider using CSS:

```
div[data-container-for='isAllDay'] {
    display: none;
}

label[for='isAllDay'] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using templates. The template documentation is very sparce, but I have used this as a trimmmed-down version of the scheduler edit window.

In the MVC razor declaration add `.Editable(e => e.TemplateId("editor"))`
then add a script to your view that contains the following:

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="title">Title</label></div>
    <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="title">
        <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" data-bind="value: title"></div>
    <div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="start">Start</label></div>
    <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="start"><span style="display: none;" class="k-widget k-datetimepicker k-header"><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: start, invisible: isAllDay" data-role="datetimepicker" data-type="date" required="" name="start" data-timezone="Etc/UTC" style="width: 100%;" class="k-input" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-label="Current focused date is 6/10/2013 12:00:00 AM"><span class="k-select" unselectable="on"><span class="k-icon k-i-calendar" unselectable="on" role="button">select</span><span class="k-icon k-i-clock" unselectable="on" role="button">select</span></span></span></span><span style="" class="k-widget k-datepicker k-header"><span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default"><input type="text" data-bind="    value: start, visible: isAllDay" data-role="datepicker" data-type="date" required="" name="start" data-timezone="Etc/UTC" style="width: 100%;" class="k-input" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-label="Current focused date is Monday, June 10, 2013"><span class="k-select" unselectable="on" role="button"><span class="k-icon k-i-calendar" unselectable="on">select</span></span></span></span><span data-bind="    text: startTimezone"></span><span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="start" style="display: none;"></span></div>
    <div class="k-edit-label">
        <label for="recurrenceRule">Repeat</label></div>
    <div class="k-edit-field" data-container-for="recurrenceRule">
        <div data-bind="value: recurrenceRule" name="recurrenceRule" data-role="recurrenceeditor"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="k-recur-view"></div></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#events-edit) event of the scheduler to hide the all day checkbox.

```
  edit: function(e) {
    e.container
     .find("[name=isAllDay]") // find the all day checkbox
     .parent() // get its wrapper
     .prev() // get the label wrapper
     .remove() // remove the label wrapepr
     .end() // get back to the checkbox wrapper
     .remove(); // remove the checkbox wrapper
  },
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ibOYUXev/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a full control over the contents of the editor dialog, you can use [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/scheduler#configuration-editable.template):

**template**

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<h3>Edit meeting</h3>
<p>
   <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>
</p>
<p>
   <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>
</p>
<p>
   <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>
</p>
</script>
```

**scheduler div**

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
   date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
   editable: {
   template: $("#editor").html()
    },
   views: [
   { type: "day" }
   ],
   dataSource: [
    {
    id: 1,
    start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
    end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
    title: "Interview"
    }
   ]});
</script>
```